# Failed to start dhcp

Tags: linux, dhcp, opensuse

I'm working on an assignment where I need to configure a LINUX-based DHCP server.

However, I had a problem where I couldn't start my DHCP.
This is the error code:

[image: Error Code]

Comment: What have you tried to do to resolve it?

Comment: It would be helpful if it showed the full error message, and you might want to provide the DHCP config as well.  What is the content of /usr/bin/systemd-tmpfiles-keep and what are its perms?

Comment: Do not post text as an image. cut-and-paste it as text.